# How to convert mysql library code to mysqli in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Help me to modify my code according to new standards and API.

I have create a file `like.php`:
I have created a function for getting result in return with ternary operator

```
function article_exists($article_id)
    {
        $article_id =(int)$article_id;
        return (mysql_result("SELECT COUNT(article_id) from articles where article_id= $article_id", 0)==0)?false:true;
    }
```

I want to use the code with mysqli_result and i m calling it from another page 
I need to get print exist when my page index.php runs

index.php

```
if(article_exists(1)===true)
    {
    echo "exist";
    }
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried first? I suspect if you look at the examples on this site, or in the PHP manual, you will be fine on your own - it is always good to give it a go!

Comment: Thanks @halfer i am editing my question so that you will resolve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

> you have to change the script like this

```
function article_exists($article_id){
    $article_id =(int)$article_id;
    return (mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT COUNT(article_id) from articles where article_id= $article_id", 0)==0)?false:true;
}

## Connection File ##
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @arun but
This is not the way i  have done ..
Pleas provide me the more  specific answer, it'll be the great help from you

Comment: As i tried your code, I m getting error as 
**Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int**

Comment: change it to mysqli_query